# How to optimize django postgres search

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I'm using postgres search on my Django project. And I must search by `title`, `content` and `tag` of `article` model. Couse of conetent could contain too many chars, search works too slow. For example, my db has 1000 articles and each article has 5000 chars there will be 5 million chars. So search will work slow. How can I optime it?

```
# models.py

class Article(models.Model):
    class Statuses(models.TextChoices):
        DRAFT = (
            "draft",
            _("Draft"),
        )
        PUBLISHED = "published", _("Published")
        BANNED = "banned", _("Banned")
        DELETED_ARTICLE = "deleted_article", _("Deleted Article")
        DELETED_AUTHOR = "deleted_author", _("Deleted Author")
        FOR_TEST = "for_test", _("For test")

    objects = ArticleQueryset.as_manager()

    title = models.CharField(verbose_name=_("title"), max_length=255)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="articles", null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    content = BleachField(
        verbose_name=_("content"), max_length=20000, validators=[MinLengthValidator(750)]
    )
    status = models.CharField(max_length=15, choices=Statuses.choices, default=Statuses.DRAFT)
    banner = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=255)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    modified_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, blank=True, null=True)
    deleted_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(default="", editable=False, max_length=255, null=False)
    read_time = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    liked_users = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="liked_articles", blank=True)
    view_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    total_users_viewed = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    # seconds
    total_users_engagement_duration = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    score = models.IntegerField(default=0, db_index=True)
    tags = TaggableManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


# filters.py

class ArticleFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):

    q = django_filters.CharFilter(method="search_filter")

    def search_filter(self, queryset, _, value):
        search_vector = (
            SearchVector(
                "title",
                weight="B",
            )
            + SearchVector(StringAgg("tags__name", delimiter=" "), weight="C")
            + SearchVector("content", weight="D")
        )
        search_query = SearchQuery(value)
        search_rank = SearchRank(search_vector, search_query)
        return (
            queryset.annotate(search=search_vector, rank=search_rank)
            .filter(search=search_query)
            .order_by("-rank")
        )

    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ["q"]


# views.py

class ArticleListView(ListView):  # pylint: disable=too-many-ancestors
    context_object_name = "articles"
    template_name = "articles/article-list.html"
    filter_class = ArticleFilter
    paginate_by = 10
    extra_context = {
        "title": _("Main page"),
        "description": _(
            "Makalam is a powerful and user-friendly platform for writers, "
            "bloggers, and readers. Publish your articles, connect with like-minded "
            "individuals, and discover new perspectives on a variety of topics."
        ),
    }

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if tag_slug := self.kwargs.get("slug"):
            tag = get_object_or_404(Tag, slug=tag_slug)
            self.tag = tag  # pylint: disable=attribute-defined-outside-init

        return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["page"] = self.request.GET.get("page")
        if tag := getattr(self, "tag", None):
            context["tag"] = tag
            # Python f-strings are not yet supported by xgettext
            context["title"] = _("Articles about %(tag)s") % {"tag": tag.name.title()}
            context["description"] = _(
                "Discover in-depth articles on %(tag)s and "
                "stay up-to-date with the latest insights, "
                "analysis, and opinions. Start reading now!"
            ) % {"tag": tag.name.title()}

        return context

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Article.objects.list(self.request.user)

        query = self.request.GET.copy()
        if tag_slug := self.kwargs.get("slug"):
            query["tags"] = tag_slug

        if self.request.path == reverse("search") and not self.request.GET.get("q", None):
            return queryset.none()

        queryset = self.filter_class(query, queryset=queryset, request=self.request).qs

        return queryset.annotate_metrics().prefetch_related("tags").select_related("author")
```